# jQuery check status

Tags: jquery, ajax

This function everytime gives **"false"**, even if `image_url` exists

```
// some .each {
    var item = $('.item', this);
    $.ajax({
        url: image_url,
        success: function() {
            item.html("true");
        },
        error: function() {
            item.html("false");
        }
    });
// }
```

Its used to check existance of `image_url` file - this variable gives url like `http://blog.com/teddybear.png`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do something like this due to the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents fetching any data from another domain.

However, there is hope! You can use the `error` event for an `<img>` element to see if it exists, like this:

```
function testImage(url) {
    $("<img />", { 
      error: function() { item.html('false'); }, 
      load: function() { item.html('true'); }
    })​​.attr('src', url);
}
```

[You can view a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6SCf5/), it tests for an image that *does* exist, waits 2 seconds then tries one that doesn't.  This uses the [`$(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) creation method to create a `<img>` element, assign events, then set the `src`, we're just checking which event gets hit as the pass/fail check.

Comment: I call this function with testImage(result);

Comment: this doesn't work - load: function() { item.html('<img src="' + result + '"/>'); }

Comment: @Happy - No need to load it again, you already have the image, you can do `item.empty().append(this);`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cKKTe/

Comment: Please give some ability to use code like this load: function() { item.html('<img src="' + result + '"/>'); }

Comment: I have to throw var result to <img src, else { throw another var }

Comment: @Happy - It's an synchronous check, so you can't return a variable here, you can call another function *from* the `load` function, but you can't return anything...this is just how asynchronous things work.  This is exactly your code: http://jsfiddle.net/cKKTe/1/ , what trouble are you having with it?